# How to using cursor in loop?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

The problem is i can't load my image and maybe i got problem on here. Maybe this code make error  "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0" sorry i cant describe what is my problem T_T. Im new in android.

> quest.setImage(Utility.getPhoto(cursor.getBlob(1))); //maybe i got
>   problem here

DbHelper.java

```
public List<Question> getAllQuestions(){
            List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5";
            dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            //==============================================
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Question quest = new Question();

                    quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                    quest.setImage(Utility.getPhoto(cursor.getBlob(1)));
                    quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(2));
                    quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(3));
                    quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(4));
                    quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(5));
                    quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(6));
                    quesList.add(quest);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            // return quest list
            return quesList;
        }
```

Question.java

```
    public Bitmap getBitmap(){
     return bmp;
}
    public void setImage(Bitmap img){
    bmp = img;
}
```

Utility.java

```
public class Utility {
    // convert from bitmap to byte array
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
    }

    // convert from byte array to bitmap
    public static Bitmap getPhoto(byte[] image) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can remove the if(cursor.moveToFirst()) statement. Cursors are returned by default positioned before the first entry. So you only need while(cursor.moveToNext()).

Comment: @hitch.united, can you show example? i'm newbie..

Comment: Of course, replace the entire 
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do {

    } while (cursor.moveToNext())
}
with a simple

while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    ....Question Code here
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your query is not returning all the 7 columns you expect.

List all the actual column names in the query (always a good practice) so it will fail faster and with a more descriptive message.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT fielName1, fieldName2, "
    + " ..., lastFieldName FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: I think the query is just failing.

Comment: probably that order by random()

Comment: supposed to be ORDER BY rand()

Comment: nice. would that throw `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: so you going out of bounds in your nonexistant result

Comment: that because my app **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0**? @JoshuaByer